# Prime faces dialog with fields in the form

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've got a form that is a simply created. What I want to do is show my dialog with the name (i.e.: the value from the `inputField`) on click. I realize the dialog happens BEFORE the action of the `commandButton`, so I'm trying to figure out how to get what the value is at that moment:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" id="confirmDialog">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
  </p:confirmDialog>

  <p:inputField id="field" value="#{myBean.myName}"/>
  <p:commandButton value="Create" update=":myForm" actionListener="#{myBean.sayHi}"> 
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Is your name actually #{myBean.myName}?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
  </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Right now the dialog box just shows an empty string. How would we do that?

With something like a `selectOneMenu`, I could just add an AJAX event. Do I really need something similar with an input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in submitting the value before confirmation just to use it in the `confirmDialog`  so the way to go is to use `onclick` event of the commandButton to change the `message="Is your name actually #{myBean.myName}?"` using javascript.

check this code, it works fine:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <p:growl id="msg" />
  <p:inputText id="field" value="#{indexBacking.input}" widgetVar="fieldWv"/>

  <p:commandButton id="cmd01" value="Create" onclick="showConfirm();"/>

  <p:confirmDialog showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" id="confirmDialog" widgetVar="confirmDialogWv">
    <f:facet name="message">
      <div id="confirmMessage"></div>
    </f:facet>
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" actionListener="#{indexBacking.sayHi()}" update="@form"/>
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('confirmDialogWv').hide();"/>
  </p:confirmDialog>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showConfirm() {
        PF('confirmDialogWv').show();
        $('#confirmMessage').empty();
        $('#confirmMessage').append("<p>Is your name actually [" + PF('fieldWv').jq.val() + "]?</p>");
      }
   </script>
 </h:form>
```

please notice that I was forced to ditch the  behavior and to use the p:confirmDialog as a standard dialog to do this.

Comment: Confirmed - Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, but this is not the way those things are meant to be used!! @StaticMaine